# Shortcode not working in CPT taxonomy

Tags: shortcode

This shortcode is working for Post, Page, Tag, Category at the title but not print output in CPT Taxonomy.

Also, I want this should also work for Description in all Post, Page, Tag, Cat, Tax.

It means the shortcode should be work all around the website.

```
// Print This Year [y]
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'y' , 'y' );
function y() {
$year = date("Y");
return "$year";
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Are you outputting the title in the cpt taxonomy correctly? You need to use `the_title()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie No, Not only in the cpt taxonomy but in all other places it's working fine. I too try to implement the_title() but not working.